# Python program that checks answer for riddles

Tags: python

I am creating a python-based chatbot for whatsapp. One of it's functionalities is to give the user a riddle to solve. The user then answers and the program will check if the answer is correct or not. However, I have trouble defining code to correctly check whether the answer is correct.

Right now I check if the user's answer is a substring of the actual answer, but this results in very simple answers like only the letter 'e' often being correct because it is often in the answer. For example:
"What comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?"
The answer is "The Letter M", with my current code however the input 'e' will also be seen as correct. I want to only have "M", "Letter M" and "The Letter M" as correct answers, but I do not want to hardcode all answers that way.

Another example, "What is broken when it's not held?". Answer: "A Promise". 
I want "Promise" or "A Promise" to be correct, but simply the letter "m" as input would give a correct response according to my current code.

This is the part of the code where it happens:

```
    if answer.lower() in answers[randomNumber].lower():
        text_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        response = "Wow, you got it correct, nice one! \n"
        text_box.send_keys(response)
    else:
        text_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name("_3u328")
        response = "Nice try, but you didn't get it correct, try again later.\n"
        text_box.send_keys(response)
```

'answer' is a string, the answer of the user. 
'answers' is a list of strings, each item is a riddle string. 
'randomNumber' is an int, the number of the current riddle.

So my question is what would be a better way to check the answer than:

```
if answer.lower() in answers[randomNumber].lower():
```

Once again refering to the example, for the answer of "The Letter M" I would like "M", "Letter M", "The Letter M" and their lowercase equivalents to be accepted answers. But not 'e' for example, which in this way is an accepted answer.

I have been thinking about this for a while but I cannot think of a way to achieve this effect without hardcoding each answer.

Comment: You can maybe use a statistic function that search few letters from the most frequent letters in the answer. It may be incorrect is some cases but most of the time it will be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get around the fact that you need to explicitly define what you consider to be a correct answer. There is no algorithm that can read your mind.

That being said, I don't think there is anything wrong with "hardcoding" the accepted answers. This could be especially cute in some JSON-y format:

```
questions = {
    "What comes once in a minute," \
    " twice in a moment but never" \
    " in a thousand years?": ["The Letter M", "Letter M", "M"],

    "What is broken when it's not held?": ["A Promise", "Promise"]
}

for question, correct_answers in questions.items():
    user_answer = input(f"{question}: ")
    if any(user_answer.lower() == answer.lower() for answer in correct_answers):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, that was incorrect.")
```